# Как заменить текст в шестнадцатеричное число?

Tags: lua

Как заменить любой текст в текстовом поле, перед знаком плюс в шестнадцатеричное число 400000? Например есть текст в текстовом поле "SSome ENG.exe"+5C1B2F, нужно заменить любой текст перед знаком плюс в шестнадцатеричное число 400000, а любое число что после знака плюс добавить уже к 0x400000.

Comment: каким образом "SSome ENG.exe" станет 400000?

Comment: Вопрос непонятен.  Вам что, просто заменить текст регекспами нужно?

Comment: Текст нужно заменить на число 400000, если нет возможности заменить любой текст перед знаком плюс, тогда можно заменить текст **"SSome ENG.exe"** который находится в текстовом поле на шестнадцатеричное число 400000. Проблема в том, что там еще +5C1B2F

Comment: @ Ainar-G: Да, нужно только заменить текст на число.

Comment: Так что ли?) https://ideone.com/IrkFP9

Comment: Простите, но лол)

Comment: Этот текст "SSome ENG.exe"+5C1B2F вводится в текстовое поле. После знака плюс в примере, может быть любое шестнадцатеричное число. Как это учесть? В вашем примере учитывается только одно значение 0x5C1B2F.

Comment: Нужно текст который находится до знака плюс заменить на 0x400000, а число что после знака плюс добавить уже к 0x400000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua не знаю, но за 10мин сляпал вот это (если я правильно понял тебя)

```
s = "\"SSome ENG.exe\"+5C1B2F"
q = string.find(s, "+")
if q>0 then
   print("yes")
   ss = string.format("%x", tonumber("0x"..string.sub(s, q+1))+ 0x400000)
   print(ss) <---- Что тебе нужно
end
```

Comment: Да, правильно, спасибо.